# How can I download specific hardware profiles and import them into android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio device manager has an "Import hardware profile" feature in the device manager. So I'm wondering how to use it? I have some specific phone types I need to import

- galaxy a 10e
- Motorola Moto G6.
- Samsung SM-N950U
- Samsung SM-G955U

Where can I download these phone hardware profiles so I can import them into android studio?